# Android Kotlin bottomNavigation weird behaviour

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

I have an application with a single activity with a bottomNavigationView which displays 3 fragments: `BreakingNewsFragment`, `SavedNewsFragment`, and `SearchNewsFragment`. They all show a list of articles fetched from the internet. From each of those 3 fragments, I can navigate to an `ArticleFragment` which displays the article in a webview by clicking on an article. When I navigate from the `BreakingNewsFragment` to `ArticleFragment` the active tab is the Breaking News tab, then press on the Saved News tab which navigates to the `SavedNewsFragment` the active tab is now the Saved News tab, when I press on the Breaking News tab which navigates back to the `BreakingNewsFragment`, the `ArticleFragment` is displayed but the active tab is still the Saved News tab. Here is my application's repository https://github.com/PopJoestar/MVVMNewsApp.

nav_graph.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/news_nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/breakingNewsFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/articleFragment"
        android:name="com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp.ui.fragments.ArticleFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right">
        <argument
            android:name="url"
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/breakingNewsFragment"
        android:name="com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp.ui.fragments.BreakingNewsFragment"
        android:label="Breaking News" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_breakingNewsFragment_to_articleFragment"
            app:destination="@id/articleFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"/>
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/savedNewsFragment"
        android:name="com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp.ui.fragments.SavedNewsFragment"
        android:label="Saved" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_savedNewsFragment_to_articleFragment"
            app:destination="@id/articleFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"/>
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/searchNewsFragment"
        android:name="com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp.ui.fragments.SearchNewsFragment"
        android:label="SearchNewsFragment"
        >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_searchNewsFragment_to_articleFragment"
            app:destination="@id/articleFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"/>
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

the main activity

```
package com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp.ui

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp.R
import com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp.db.ArticleDatabase
import com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp.repository.NewsRepository
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_news.*

class NewsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    lateinit var viewModel: NewsViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news)

        val navHostFrag = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.newsNavHostFragment) as NavHostFragment
        navController   = navHostFrag.navController

        val newsRepository = NewsRepository(ArticleDatabase(this))
        val newsViewModelProviderFactory = NewsViewModelProviderFactory(newsRepository)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, newsViewModelProviderFactory).get(NewsViewModel::class.java)

        bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }


}
```

The activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.NewsActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/newsNavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/news_nav_graph"
            />


    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/design_default_color_surface"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate your articleFragment into a separated xml file. because the behavior of navbar and fragmentContainerView it self include menus.xml and nav graph.xml globally.

Just Imagine your menu has 3 index but in your navGraph has 4 index.